# NodeJS : Multer not saving file

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

I am working on a project where I need to save a file in a folder,

Here is my relevant code :

```
   <div class="content ui segment" id="two">
      <form  method="POST" action = "/documents/uploadDoc" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Upload new file</h2>
        <br>
        <input class='button' type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
        <input type="submit" name = "Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

My multer code :

```
var multer = require('multer');


const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination : (req,file,cb) => {
    cb(null,'tempSave/');
  },
  filename : (req,file,cb) => {
    cb(null,file.originalname)
  }
})

const saveFile = multer({ storage : fileStorage});
```

And my router :

```
router.post("/uploadDoc", saveFile.single('filename')  ,function(req,res,next){
  console.log("Uploading");
  console.log(req.body);
  var fileName = req.body.filename;
  console.log(fileName);
  
});
```

There isn't any error, but the file is not getting saved in the required place. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you check do you have `tempSave` folder in the root of your server directory? If not, create it and try it again.